# Recursive wget via PHP exec() fetches only first page?

Tags: php, exec, wget

The following wget command does a good job at recursively crawling the full domain, saving the downloaded files in a single folder, and then deleting it all:

```
wget --delete-after -r -nd http://www.example.com/
```

When run from the command line, this works perfectly. When run via PHP's exec (or system, shell_exec, passthru) as follows, it only fetches the index page, but seems to go no deeper than that:

```
exec('wget --delete-after -r -nd http://www.example.com/');
```

If this were a permissions issue, I'd think it wouldn't download the index page either, but it does (noticeable when I take out '--delete-after').

There's no robots.txt involved, and no output is shown if I pass it through echo. What am I missing?

Comment: if you put an empty array as the second parameter and dump it after the execution, what would there be in the array? It's the output container. Is there any reason in it why it stops?

Comment: The array comes out empty: array(0) { }

Comment: and if you pass the third param, what is the value of it after the execution? Also, can you try adding -v to wget params and dump the output after this?

Comment: That results in array(0) { } and int(8). It goes one level deeper if I add -O /some/file/nginx/can/access.txt, but once more it goes no further than that.

Comment: this is not run under *nix, is it?

Comment: It is. CentOS6, nginx/php-fpm, Wget 1.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a permissions issue after all, as adding the --directory-prefix param fixed it.

```
wget --delete-after -q -r -nd -P /home/example.com/public_html/tmp/ http://www.example.com
```

I set the prefix to a directory that php-fpm can surely access, whereas previously I frankly had no idea where it was saving the files to temporarily ('.' is the default directory, but where would that be?).